# Using Python to Find Integer Solutions to System of Linear Equations

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program to solve for all the positive integer solutions of a polynomial of the form `x_1 + 2x_2 + ... + Tx_T = a` subject to `x_0 + x_1 + ... + x_T = b`.

For example, by brute-force I can show that the only positive integer solution to `x_1 + 2x_2 = 4` subject to `x_0 + x_1 + x_2 = 2` is `(0,0,2)`. However, I would like a program to do this on its own.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SO doesn't support LaTeX, unfortunately, and that edit by @HaveNoDisplayName is pretty useless.  can you reformat your equations in pseudo-code to make them readable?

Comment: The solution should be `(0, 0, 2)` right?

Comment: Yes it should. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Numpy Linear Algebra](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) to solve a system of equations, the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. In your case, you can consider the following vectors:

```
import numpy as np
# range(T): coefficients of the first equation
# np.ones(T): only 'ones' as the coefficients of the second equation 
A = np.array([range(T), np.ones(T)) # Coefficient matrix
B = np.array([a, b]) # Ordinate or “dependent variable” values
```

And then find the solution as follows:

```
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
```

Finally you can implement a `solve` method passing the variables `T, a b`:

```
import numpy as np
def solve(T, a, b):
    A = np.array([range(T), np.ones(T)])
    B = np.array([a, b])
    return np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
```

**Integer solutions:**
If you want only integer solutions then you are looking at a [system of linear diophantine equations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)

> every system of linear Diophantine equations may be written: 
>   **AX = C**, where **A** is an *m×n* matrix of integers, **X** is an *n×1* column matrix of unknowns and **C** is an *m×1* column matrix of integers.

Every system of linear diophantine equation may be solved by computing the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of its matrix.

Comment: The answer doesn't have much to do with the question being asked. Why all  this talk about Numpy / least squares when the question is explicitly about integer solutions? The part about integer solutions is two links to Wikipedia, thanks very much.